# PostgreSQL is shut down

Tags: postgresql

We are using PostgreSQL with Thingworx. But suddenly the PostgreSQL service is not running. We don't have a backup of the data. We need to fix this issue without any data loss. Can I get help to resolve this issue?

my log file says:

```
 FATAL:  the database system is starting up
 LOG:  database system was interrupted; last known up at 2021-08-17 16:46:12 IST
 FATAL:  the database system is starting up
 FATAL:  the database system is starting up
 LOG:  invalid primary checkpoint record
 LOG:  invalid secondary checkpoint record
 PANIC:  could not locate a valid checkpoint record
 FATAL:  the database system is starting up
 LOG:  startup process (PID 71112) was terminated by exception 0xC0000409
 HINT:  See C include file "ntstatus.h" for a description of the hexadecimal value.
 LOG:  aborting startup due to startup process failure
 LOG:  database system is shut down
```

As per the Hint, I searched for 0xC0000409 in `ntstatus.h`. It says `STACK_BUFFER_OVERRUN`.

Answer (score 0):

You are running an old PostgreSQL release (v10 or older), and it looks like the files in `pg_wal` (or `pg_xlog` in 9.6 and below) are removed or corrupted.

Your only hope is to run `pg_resetwal` (or `pg_resetxlog`). That might enable your database to start, but it will cause data loss. After this, try to dump the database and restore it to a new cluster (created with `initdb`). You probably have to clean up data manually to make them consistent.

Make sure to backup all files before you start experimenting. If I were you, I'd hire an expert for the recovery attempt. Be ready for data loss.

Comment: Is there any other way to recover the database without any data loss?

Comment: If there were, I would have told you. The database is badly wrecked.

Comment: oh okay. Since potgresql service is not running, Is it possible to take a backup now?

Comment: Yes, just copy all the files that belong to the database cluster.

Comment: we have taken the full backup of the data folder(C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.6\data), can we now proceed to run pg_resetxlog?

Comment: Good luck. And remember that there are no guarantees that you can rescue any of your data.

Comment: I did the reset , and tried to start the postgresql service but it didn't start and in logs, I found this.  LOG:  database system was shut down at 
FATAL:  the database system is starting up
 FATAL:  could not access status of transaction 446198856
 DETAIL:  Could not open file "pg_clog/01A9": No such file or directory.
 LOG:  startup process (PID 177596) exited with exit code 1
LOG:  aborting startup due to startup process failure LOG:  database system is shut down. What should I do next?     The pg_clog folder is empty.

Comment: Then you are lost. I get the impression that some smart person deleted the `pg_xlog` and `pg_clog` files, thinking that they were only log files (space ran out?). You can create artificial ones, but that will resurrect all deleted rows. If you want to salvage these data, you **need** to hire an expert.

Comment: Can you tell me how to create the artificial file?

Comment: This is a Q&A forum. I cannot give you a tutorial on the internals of PostgreSQL and data recovery here.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for helping out so far.